# How do I ignore null values in t-sql function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am doing an outer join between two market data tables. The two tables have trading volume reported differently, therefor I need to query them separately and then sum the results.

Issue is that second query is for a trade condition that doesn't happen often and therefore return no result sometimes. So c.volume has value and md.volume is null and I get null as the result of the addition.

How can I make it treat the null as 0?

```
select 
    c.the_time, c.symbol, c.volume + md.volume 
from 
    -- These are single shares
    (select 
         (time_stamp / 100000) as the_time, symbol, 
         sum(size) as volume 
     from 
         [20160510]
     where 
         price_field = 0
         and (size > 0
         and tradecond != 0)
     group by 
         (time_stamp / 100000), symbol) as c
full outer join 
    (select 
         d.the_time, d.symbol, d.volume as volume 
     from 
         -- These are single shares when multiplied by -1
        (select 
             (time_stamp / 100000) as the_time, symbol, sum(size) * -1 as volume 
         from 
             [20160510]
         where 
             price_field = 0
             and size < 0
         group by 
             (time_stamp / 100000), symbol) as d) as md on md.the_time = c.the_time 
                                                        and md.symbol = c.symbol
```

Comment: easiest way is to use `ISNULL(md.volume,0)` to convert null values to a number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should consider using COALESCE. 
Note that you can also use ISNULL but COALESCE is ANSI standard function. See **[reference link](http://www.itprotoday.com/software-development/coalesce-vs-isnull).**

Your query after using COALESCE will be like

```
select 
    c.the_time, c.symbol, COALESCE(c.volume,0) + COALESCE(md.volume ,0)
from 
    -- These are single shares
    (select 
         (time_stamp / 100000) as the_time, symbol, 
         sum(size) as volume 
     from 
         [20160510]
     where 
         price_field = 0
         and (size > 0
         and tradecond != 0)
     group by 
         (time_stamp / 100000), symbol) as c
full outer join 
    (select 
         d.the_time, d.symbol, d.volume as volume 
     from 
         -- These are single shares when multiplied by -1
        (select 
             (time_stamp / 100000) as the_time, symbol, sum(size) * -1 as volume 
         from 
             [20160510]
         where 
             price_field = 0
             and size < 0
         group by 
             (time_stamp / 100000), symbol) as d) as md on md.the_time = c.the_time 
                                                        and md.symbol = c.symbol
```